# Change default directory when downloading images from URL in keras

Tags: keras

Im trying to download flowers dataset from URL using the below code:

```
dataset_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower photos',origin=dataset_URL,cache_dir='D:\\flowers',untar=True)
```

I have specified the cache_dir folder as D drive and yet the dataset is still getting saved in default directory of keras in C drive --> C:\tmp.keras\datasets\flower_photos (in python the path appears like this '/tmp\.keras\datasets\flower photos')

Need a solution how to make sure the dataset is getting downloaded in the folder specified in D drive and not getting downloaded by default in c drive keras/dataset.

I tried specifying cache_dir = 'D:\flowers' and was expecting the datatset to get downloaded in the drive instead of default c drive

Comment: The docs say about [filename](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/get_file) (you first parameter): "Name of the file. If an absolute path /path/to/file.txt is specified the file will be saved at that location. "   So when you change it from `'flower photos'` to `'D:/flowers/flower photos'` it should work (when the directory `flowers` exists)

Comment: Great!  It was pretty  simple. How could I miss the simple instruction on tensorflow. It was getting downloaded to the specific folder now. Also initially it wasn't getting extracted. But then I changed the 'slashes' in fname and cache_dir path and made them same. Then it extracted the folder as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to run this piece of code and give it a try?

```
dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True,
                                cache_dir='./')
```